# Ruby on Rails application couldn't be started: no such file to load --multi_json (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prawn

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I wanted to install Prawn Library. But running `gem install prawn` fails and I get `ttfunk requires ruby version 1.9.3` . So I had to add gem 'prawn', '0.12.0' to the Gemfile, and I noticed that there is no such file in our project, so I added it under:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'rails', '2.3.5'
gem 'prawn', '0.12.0'
```

This is the `gem list`:

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
afm (0.2.2)
arel (3.0.1)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.22)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
faraday (0.9.1)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
git (1.2.9.1)
hashery (2.1.1)
hike (1.2.1)
httpauth (0.2.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.2)
json (1.6.5)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.8.2)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mysql (2.9.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
oauth2 (0.6.1)
passenger (3.0.11)
pdf-reader (1.3.3)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prawn (0.12.0)
prawn-core (0.6.3)
rack (1.4.1, 1.0.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (2.3.5)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
rush (0.6.8)
searchlogic (2.5.19)
session (3.2.0)
sprockets (2.1.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
ttfunk (1.0.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
validatable (1.6.7)
vote_fu (0.0.11)
```

So you can notice that multi_json is installed as a gem. I tried uninstalling and re-installing it, I also checked its permissions, and tried to restart nginx server several times, but none of this worked. I'm not able to solve this problem, I opened the dependencies.rb file where the error points to and I found this:

```
def require(file, *extras) #:nodoc:
    if Dependencies.load?
      Dependencies.new_constants_in(Object) { super }
    else
```

#line 58        `super`

```
 end
  rescue Exception => exception  # errors from required file
    exception.blame_file! file
    raise
  end
```

Please help me figure this out.

UPDATE: Big thanks for Mateusz Czerwiński I added `gem 'multi_json', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.2'` to my gemfile and run bundle install, and the first error is gone. but now I'm getting this error:

```
no such file to load -- i18n/backend/fallbacks (MissingSourceFile)
```

I checked the gem list and I have i18n (0.4.2) installed.I also checked if i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb file is there, and I found it under ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.2/lib/i18n/backend, and I changed its permissions. But still it didn't work.

I copied the gems required by multi_json from /usr/local/lib/ruby to /multi_json/ruby. This seems to fix the gems errors, but I'm having the following error now:

```
Error message:
    uninitialized constant FedenaPlugin::Authorization
Exception class:
    NameError
```

I don't understand why all these errors are here, and why installing a gem caused my application to stop. And I don't understand what the last error indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary gems, for fedena these are the gems you should have:

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.0.22)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
faraday (0.9.1)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
git (1.2.9.1)
hashery (2.1.1)
httpauth (0.2.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
json (1.6.5)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mysql (2.9.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
oauth2 (0.6.1)
passenger (3.0.11)
rack (1.4.1, 1.0.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rush (0.6.8)
searchlogic (2.5.19)
session (3.2.0)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
validatable (1.6.7)
vote_fu (0.0.11)
```

So uninstall other gems, and remove multi_json folder in addition to Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files, and try this command:

```
gem install prawn -v 0.6.3
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'multi_json', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.2'
```

and then execute `bundle install`. There could be a problem with dependencies and not enough gems in your Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think it worked, but now I have this error: no such file to load -- i18n/backend/fallbacks (MissingSourceFile), do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think it is the same problem, add this gem https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n. Better for you is using default gems generated by `$ rails new app_gen` in your console. It can help in near future.